# Question about detail view in UISplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have just begun to check out the UISplitViewController and I have seen in the tutorials that there are two viewcontrollers involved. One master and one detail. But if there are only two viewcontrollers and I have let say 10 rows in the master view that uses tables, webview and e.g. imageviews. Wouldn't that be chaos if I don't have one detail viewcontroller for each row? Have I misunderstood something about this viewcontroller?

Comment: I think, you can use different view controllers for each row and it will be ok!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UISplitViewController doesn't do anything out of the ordinary, it just allows you to have two viewControllers side by side, and only available [for the iPad](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) (I'm mentioning this, because you tagged it under "iPhone")

You're the one responsible on how the things on the detail are presented, so you could have 3 different type of view controllers, and swap them as the user clicks on the (for example) rows of the tableView on the left.

Comment: Also, in most split view controller examples there's just one detail view controller and the content is simply updated when a new row is selected. So it's up to your design.